# Override data_template in Flask-admin ImageUploadField

Tags: field, flask-admin

I'm trying to remove the delete-checkbox from the HTML markup stored in data_template. Is there a way to only override the data_template or do I have to subclass the whole ImageUploadField?

ImageUploadField: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/form/upload/#ImageUploadInput

Answer (score 3):

You have to first create an instance of the widget and then override the field itself. Solution:

```
class ImageFieldWidget(admin.form.ImageUploadInput):
    data_template = ('<div class="image-thumbnail">'
                     ' <img %(image)s>'
                     '</div>'
                     '<input %(file)s>')

class ImageField(admin.form.ImageUploadField):
    widget = ImageFieldWidget()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need!